# replacing character in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with many columns. The values in columns start with "[" and end with "]". Like "[Sinopharm]". I want to replace "[" and "]" with nothing. I did the following code but not both can be changed.

```
data['q3'] = data['q3'].str.replace('[', '')
```

Important: I want to replace both at once and to all columns. Like 'q4', 'q5' etc

Comment: Why not chain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_data = data.replace({r'[\[\]]': ''}, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data['q3'] = data['q3'].str.replace('[', '').replace(']','')
```

Comment: This works too but the accepted one can replace all in the whole datasheet. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can use the strip() as a possibility

```
data['q3'] = data['q3'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('[]'))
```

Comment: `strip` is really the right tool for the given problem. Just a note, for individual columns you can do `data['q3'].str.strip('[]')`. Likewise, it can be applied to the whole dataframe (or multiple columns) by `data.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('[]'))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
cols = df.filter(like='q').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r'\[|\]', '', regex=True))
```

```
# Before
print(df)
            q3           q4           q5
0  [Sinopharm]  [Sinopharm]  [Sinopharm]

# After
print(df)
          q3         q4         q5
0  Sinopharm  Sinopharm  Sinopharm
```